# Linux port based routing

Tags: linux, routes, iptables, portforwarding

I have a requirement to host a java application on a server which can simulate multiple devices each one with separate IP address. The scalability requirements are so large that I cannot think of launching VMs or any containers.

The way I thought about supporting this is to have the application listen on a particular port on 127.0.0.1 , add a route to forward all the packets destined to say 192.168.0.1/24 (internal addresses where clients connected to my server will send packets) forward to 127.0.0.1:

Is this the best way of implementing or any other better options available.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple loopback interface, in addition to 127.0.0.1, you can create a loopback interface on 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3, etc... Each one of them will be a loopback interface of its own.

ifconfig tells you:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 353847  bytes 99880673 (95.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 353847  bytes 99880673 (95.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that the netmask is 255.0.0.0